# Proving that the limit of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin x+x}{x}=1$

Tags: limits

How would we go about writing a proof for this statement? I know how to prove for $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ using Squeeze Theorem but how would we prove for this? Thanks

Comment: Then you can repeat the same proof with $\cos x+1\leqslant \sin x/x+1\leqslant \tan x+1$

Comment: @daruma It looks like you're trying to resolve $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$ rather than $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ as in the question. (and besides, $\frac{\sin x}{x} \leq \tan x$ isn't true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use the squeeze theorem.  Since 
$$-1 \leq \sin x \leq 1$$
then 
$$-1 + x \leq \sin x + x \leq 1 + x$$
and for $x > 0,$ 
$$\frac{-1+x}{x} \leq \frac{\sin x + x}{x} \leq \frac{1+x}{x}.$$

Then $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pm1+x}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pm 1}{x}+1 = 0 + 1 = 1$$

Comment: Is there a possible epsilon delta proof you could add on to it?

Comment: @adil.a You can certainly do an $\varepsilon\text{-}\delta$ proof of the last limit $\frac{\pm 1 + x}{x},$ but any direct $\varepsilon\text{-}\delta$ proof of the original fact will likely use the proof of the squeeze theorem in one of the steps.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{sin(x)}{x} \leq \frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$ and $\frac{1}{x} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

So,

$\frac{sin(x)+x}{x} = \frac{sin(x)}{x} + \frac{x}{x} =\frac{sin(x)}{x} + 1\rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow \infty.$